# findstr command variable expansion in path in for loop batch script(windows, batch script)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

```
echo off
set "MasterFolder=C:\Users\Development\test_folder"
SetLocal EnableDelayedexpansion
@FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /s "%MasterFolder%\*.txt"') DO (
    set /a "idx+=1"
    set "FileName[!idx!]=%%~nxf"
    set "FilePath[!idx!]=%%~dpFf"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%idx%) do (
    echo [%%i] "!FileName[%%i]!"

    set "loc=%MasterFolder%\!FileName[%%i]!"
    echo path: %MasterFolder%\!FileName[%%i]!
    echo loc: !loc!
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%1 in ('findstr /o "^" "%MasterFolder%\test_1.txt"') DO (
        set new_pos=%%1
        echo new_pos !new_pos!
    )
)
```

The above code works, However, the following codes do not work.

```
echo off
... 
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%1 in ('findstr /o "^" "%MasterFolder%\!FileName[%%i]!"') DO (
        set new_pos=%%1
        echo new_pos !new_pos!
    )
)
```

```
echo off
...
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%1 in ('findstr /o "^" "!loc!"') DO (
        set new_pos=%%1
        echo new_pos !new_pos!
    )
)
```

All I did was replacing **test_1.txt to !FileName[%%i]!**, or use a new variable and replace all as **"!loc!"**.

But the last two codes do not work, and I need this manner, since it get file names in the folder automatically by the first for loop.

I guess there is an error either in findstr, or variable expansion order, but it is hard for me to figure it out.

Comment: `, but it is hard for me to figure it out.` Perhaps a simple `echo` of your `findstr` command before the loop could help

Comment: @jeb Hi jeb, again! Yes, has self destruction for a while, but was a different issue in naming. I named the batch file, as 'findstr.bat' first time. 
Only get
```
FINDSTR: No search strings
```
error now from the last 2 codes.

Comment: Defensive programming might use `"%__APPDIR__%\findstr.exe"`.

Comment: You should examine your variables. `echo %%i` and `set Filename`

Comment: @jeb What do you mean with *echo*? Yes, I checked the whole command *findstr* command with echo, there is no problem, same as in the first code.

Comment: @lit still have **FINDSTR: No search strings** error message.

Comment: @jeb I checked *%%i* variable, there is no issue in there, I am not sure about *set Filename* suggestion. Do you mean reassign Filename variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious!

When using `!file...`, you introduce an exclamation mark into the line.

This triggers [phase 5 (delayed epxansion phase) of the parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/463115).
In that phase the variables are expanded **and carets are used to escape the next character**, independent where they are (quoted or not)!

Therefore you your search string `"^"` is trasformed to `""`.

Simply double the caret to `findstr /o "^^" !File...`

#### The exclamation effect is a bit unexpected

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo One Caret "^"
echo One Caret "^" and a bang ^^!
```

Output

> One Caret "^"
> One Caret "" and a bang !

Comment: Yes, wow, it was obvious, I had to more focus on the error message itself. Digging in a wrong part, or partially related, as you mentioned, **carets are used to escape the next character**. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeyCho Okay, to be fair. It's not so obvious, I had to test it, too, before I recognized the problem.